# CORS with an included inline script for a 3rd party service

Tags: reactjs, webpack, cors, create-react-app

I've just ejected from `create-react-app` and I continue running into CORS issues. I've tried the following inside of the `webpack-dev-server`:

```
headers: {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
},
```

And also with the express middleware:

```
before(app, server) {
  app.use(cors());
  // ...
}
```

None of these approaches work, so I've opted to start my browser for local development by disabling web security. The issue seems to be that all API calls do get the appropriate `headers`, however, the resource throwing the error is an inline script that we include inside of the `index.html`. Any ideas?

Error in the browser:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at '***URL***' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: Which error do you have?

Comment: updated, @rpadovani

Comment: Can you verify that you're getting those headers served back to you, i.e. what does the response look like in your browser dev tools? AFAIK you don't need to specify Content-Type or Authorization in the allow-headers list either, but that ought not be a problem.

Comment: How can I verify that, @Rup?

Comment: If you're using Chrome, have the developer tools open as you make the request and then you can use the Network tab to see the response headers and body. I expect other browsers will do this too, but don't know exactly how: wherever you found the JavaScript console to see your error I expect.

Comment: @Detuned please check server side code(http://localhost:3000), whether **CORS** filter enabled or not

Comment: `***URL***` must return these headers, you can not set them from the requesting end, that is not how CORS works.

Comment: I see what the issue is... all API calls going through WebPack have the headers, however, the resource throwing the error is actually an inline script. We have an external resource that is required to simply inject into our webpage.

Any ideas on how to resolve this sort of CORS issue?

Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: A guess, could it be the combination of domain '*' and credentials true?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, @RemcoGerlich

Comment: I had a problem last week ago where the browser complained if my CORS headers had both allow-origin: '*' and allow-credentials: true. It worked when I put specific domains in allow-origin. But I'm just guessing while in a meeting.